# Затруднение с перечислением всех слов, длиной не более заданной, удовлетворяющие требованиям

Tags: алгоритм, комбинаторика

у меня возникла небольшая неопределенность вида в следующем простом задании:

Задан алфавит набором символом. Перечислить все слова, длиной не более заданной, удовлетворяющие требованиям, определенным индивидуальным заданием.Алфавит состоит из символов w, e, r, t. Составить слова длиной до 5 символов, состоящие из разных символов.

Следовательно, все слова из 1-2-3-4 символов (ведь по условию - до пяти) и СОСТОЯЩИЕ ИЗ РАЗНЫХ символов - т.е все эти комбинации тогда? т.е у меня по условию входит все размещения данных комбинаций (общее количество слов - 64)

То есть:
1 - w e r t
2 - we rt ew tr wt tw wr rw (всего 12)
3 - wer wet wte twe tew rew ert erw tre и т.д... (всего 24)
4 - wert ertw twre и т.д... (всего 24)

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, в чём состоит вопрос, своего кода не приведено.

Пример рекурсивной генерации размещений на Delphi (символы в строках нумеруются с единицы!)

```
procedure Arrangement(var A: string; n, k: Integer; s: string);
  var
    i: Integer;
    t: Char;
  begin
    if k = 0 then
      Writeln(s)
    else
      for i := 1 to n do begin
        t := A[i];
        A[i] := A[n];  //store used item in the tail
        Arrangement(A, n - 1, k - 1, s + t + ' ');  //recursion without tail
        A[i] := t;  //get it back
      end;
  end;

var
  src: string;
begin
  src := 'asdf';
  Arrangement(src, 4, 2, '');
  Readln;

a f
a s
a d
s a
s f
s d
d a
d s
d f
f a
f s
f d
```